# Start new shell with positional parameters

Tags: shell, arguments, parameter, interactive

With Python, I can start a session with positional parameters:

```
$ python3 - aa
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv[1]
'aa'
```

However it does not seem to be possible with shell:

```
$ sh - aa
sh: aa: No such file or directory
```

How can I start a new shell with positional parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-s` option for that. From [the POSIX description of `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

```
sh -s [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
       [argument...]

-s
Read commands from the standard input.
If there are no operands and the -c option is not specified, the -s option shall be assumed.
```

So:

```
% sh -s foo bar
sh-3.2$ echo "$@"
foo bar
```